# How do I evaluate Python code from a string quickly?

Tags: python, string, performance, eval

I'm writing a program that has to execute Python code from a string millions of times. Is there a faster way to do this than using `eval()`? Running the code in `eval()` takes about 100 microseconds, and running it embedded in the program only takes 8 microseconds. Is there a method similar to `eval()` that takes less time to execute?

Comment: If the eval returns a “function to do work” (eg. lambda or other callable), the result can be cached and executed again much faster as the entire parsing stage is skipped: it’s approximately as if an existing method was called. (Doesn’t apply if a different string is always used: however, even in such cases, perhaps commonality can be extracted?)

Comment: you shouldn't use `eval` but [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead

Comment: @aws_apprentice, `ast.literal_eval` is definitely safer, but it doesn't do all that `eval()` does. OP, this is an important point: where are the strings coming from? If they're from untrusted sources you definitely shouldn't be running them through `eval()`. That's a _major_ security issue. Good use cases for `eval()` are few and far between.

Comment: the `eval` is evaluating an equation, such as `x ** 2 + y`. It is creating a "graph" by iterating through different values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Then have the eval expression be, eg: “lambda x, y: x ** 2 + y” (or don’t even use the eval, although perhaps this is for a graphing calculator, where a user can enter an expression as a function :). Then let f = eval(expression_returning_lambda); and use r = f(x, y), where f is **only created once** for the same expression input and called many times..

Comment: Again, if it's for something like a graphing calculator do _not_ let users enter arbitrary expressions. Be _very, very careful_ about what you `eval()`.

Comment: Can you share some more context for this? Based on the limited information we have, I don’t think using `eval()` is justified.

Comment: I'm taking a string using `input()` so it has to be executed from a string. I don't care about security risks, since I'll be the only one using it.

Comment: "I don't care about security risks, since I'll be the only one using it"—you should _always_ care about security risks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would restructure your code so that it doesn't have to be `eval`ed (e.g., take a function argument instead of a string)

If the equation absolutely must come from a string, you could compile it beforehand:

```py
In [1]: x = y = 0

In [2]: %timeit eval('x ** 2 + y')
5.95 µs ± 223 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [3]: code = compile('x ** 2 + y', '<string>', 'eval')

In [4]: %timeit eval(code)
608 ns ± 9.88 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Rather than having `eval` compile the string to bytecode every time it is called, `compile` does that beforehand.